# Wi-Fi stops working when running Node.js server

Tags: network, macos, wifi, reboot

I'm trying to run a game server using WebSocket and node.js. It works fine for about 5 minutes and then all of a sudden the game stops and I can no longer connect to the internet.

When I hover over the Wi-Fi symbol in the menu bar, it shows the spinning pinwheel of death. When I open System Preferences and go to the network section, it becomes unresponsive. The only thing that fixes the internet is rebooting. When I log out, it shows a black screen with my cursor. I'm on Mac OS Sierra. this is my log file from console: [image]

Comment: Have you checked the console (applications -> utilities) for any output regarding WiFi?

Comment: @Kevin Gravher ive updated my question